# CQL multiple range select

Tags: cassandra, cql

I tried to run this query in cassandra DB, but can't get result:

```
SELECT smth..smthz, else..elsez FROM CF
```

Is it possible to use multiple range select expressions in CQL?

Comment: why not workout what you want to select in your application ?

Comment: I can, but just wanted to know is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CASE queries are not supported in cassandra. You have to manipulate in your code to achieve that functionality